# Grails- find the location from lat, lang

Tags: google-maps, grails, groovy, geolocation

How do i find the address from the lat, lang values. i am unable to
get any information from the google. i have to write a service to send
the location to android app when they sent lat, lang values. i have
installed geolocation plugin. i dont know how to use that in the case
of sending the services. i have read this document
http://grails.org/plugin/geolocation. but that requirement is
different from me. they are getting the values from gsp and
caluclating in js page

Comment: You'll have to use a mapping service to do this.

Comment: can i call a google map service from my service or controller class?? @igor Artamonov

Answer (score 1):

The service you're looking for is known as "Reverse Geocoding".  Google provides a service that does this as part of its Maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding